# Swift app crashes with (lldb) as only debug output after @IBAction with a UIButton sender

Tags: ios, swift

I see after researching that this particular debug output isn't super rare, but the causes can differ pretty greatly. I'm new to iOS development and have been trying to figure out why the app is crashing, but can't crack it. I'm going to supply a lot of different code snippets, because I only have a hunch as to what's actually wrong.

I'm partially following along to [this video tutorial for a ToDo list](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=war0gHL26ns), while differing in some ways. Most notably, I chose not to start with a Tabbed Application template and instead looked up a way to unwind views.

Here is the simple object manager class that the tutorial has you create:

```
import UIKit

var rmndrMgr = ReminderManager()

struct reminder {
    var name = "none"
    var description = "none"
}

class ReminderManager: NSObject {

    var reminders = [reminder]()

    func addReminder(name: String, description: String) {
        reminders.append(reminder(name: name, description: description))
    }
}
```

Below is my first view controller:

```
import UIKit

@objc(ToDoListTableViewController)
class ToDoListTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func unwindToList(segue:UIStoryboardSegue){
//        var source = segue.sourceViewController
//            as AddToDoItemViewController
//        var item: ToDoItem? = source.toDoItem
//        if item != nil {
//            self.toDoItems.addObject(item)
//            self.tableView.reloadData()
//        }
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return rmndrMgr.reminders.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "Default")

        cell.textLabel!.text = rmndrMgr.reminders[indexPath.row].name

        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = rmndrMgr.reminders[indexPath.row].description

        return cell
    }
}
```

And the second view controller:

```
import UIKit

class AddToDoViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var textReminder: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var textDescription: UITextField!       

    //Events
    @IBAction func addReminder_click(sender: UIButton) {

    }


    //Touch Functions

    //UITextFieldDelegate
    //"first responder" is the keyboard. resign it when user presses return key
    //basically gets rid of the keyboard when user submit
    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)

        println("clicked out")
    }
}
```

And here is what my "add" view actually looks like:
[Removed because I don't have the reputation to post images]
[imgur link instead](http://imgur.com/RSLEUhU)

I have navigation bars with UIBarButtonItems at the top of the views. Right now the "Close" and "Done" buttons (which live in the navigation bar) do the same thing: unwind the user back to the main list. Ideally the "Submit" button (which is not in the navigation bar, just on the normal screen) will add what the user has typed to an array that will be shown on the other view. The "Done" button will likely be removed or refactored.

The current behavior, though, is for the app to crash with the debug text of (lldb) when I click on the "Submit" button regardless of what code is inside it's action function. I am reasonably sure it is hooked up correctly because I have tried both writing out the function signature and Control-dragging from the button to the code to generate it.

I believe the problem lies with the navigation bars, as those were lifted from a different ToDo list tutorial. However, I am unable to get a descriptive enough log to really know why or figure out how to fix it. I'll gladly post more information from my Xcode should it be required, so please just ask. I'd be super grateful if someone could help me identify my mistake and learn from it.

Comment: Add the link to the image you removed. Where is the `Submit` button in your code?

Comment: Sorry, was editing it while you posted. The Submit button is the @IBAction in the second view controller

Comment: Are you sure you don't have the `action` for the submit button tied to an old `action`? Select the button in interface builder and click the **Show the Connections inspector**. Also, naming a `UIButton` in an iOS project `addReminder_click` seems silly. Don't you think it should be `addReminder_tap` or `addReminder`?

Comment: Point taken as far as the naming is concerned, makes sense. When I look in the connections inspector, I see [this](http://imgur.com/bKSmvle) which I'm pretty sure is wired correctly, right?

edit: I'm going to try removing the action and tying it to a new one

Comment: After removing the action and the button, and re-adding them, the connections inspector looks the same and it still crashes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I bet you added a breakpoint in the XCode editor. Try hitting typing 'continue' into the console that appears with 'lldb'. If it was a run time error, you would see error messages.

The blue arrow is a breakpoint for reference.
[image]

Comment: Wow, you were right. Thanks for taking the time to help. It was a very simple mistake that would have really derailed me. I have no idea how I added that. Thanks again.

Comment: Oh my God, this has just happened to me right now...I was driving me insane. Thank you, I don't know why and overall how I added that breakpoint... :(

Comment: And also you can see the Breakpoints in the "breakpoint tab" which is in the left project window, you can disable breakpoints from there.

Answer (score 1):

```
@objc(ToDoListTableViewController)
```

Why this is there? Are you trying to use CoreData?
Right click on the button and see where is linked.

Comment: That was to get my views to unwind properly. I'm not aware of a better way yet, though open to one. Right clicking on the button shows its touch up inside movement linked to the addReminder action on the Add view controller